# Query Eventlog Records Between Dates

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wql

I am writing a VBScript which attempts to query the WMI system logs for start up and shutdowns within the current month and unfortunately I'm hitting an automation error with the query I have created.

I have a function that will dynamically create a UTC for the start and end of the month (at least I think it does and it looks right) and then add it to the query string, which looks like this:

```
Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent
Where Logfile = 'System' and
  (EventCode = '12' or EventCode = '13') AND
  (TimeWritten is between '2015101000000.000000-000' and '2015131235959.000000-000')
```

I have tried substituting the single quotes for double quotes (using `CHR(34)` as I don't know any better).

I hoped somebody may be able to point out the error in my ways and explain why this query is not working.

Comment: You can use normal date formats (e.g. `10/10/2015`) in  your queries too which is much easier and then allows you to do date formulas like `TimeWritten >= Date - 1 AND TimeWritten <= Date` (to get yesterday's events). You can play around with it to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't have a `between` operator and both your dates are invalid (you have `yyyyMddHHmmss.ffffff±zzz` when you should have `yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff±zzz`).

Change

```sql
TimeWritten is between '2015101000000.000000-000' and '2015131235959.000000-000'
```

into

```sql
TimeWritten >= '20150101000000.000000-000' and TimeWritten <= '20150131235959.000000-000'
```

Comment: A million thanks indeed, not only did I miss that missing single digit but I have also learnt that WQL doesn't have a between operator.  I have corrected and successfully reran my code.